# Why does concatenating a boolean value return an integer?

Tags: python

In python, you can concatenate boolean values, and it would return an integer. Example:

```
>>> True
True
>>> True + True
2
>>> True + False
1
>>> True + True + True
3
>>> True + True + False
2
>>> False + False
0
```

Why? Why does this make sense?

I understand that `True` is often represented as `1`, whereas `False` is represented as `0`, but that still does not explain how adding two values together of the same type returns a completely different type.

Comment: What was your expectation, anyway? What does "concatenate" mean in the context of scalar types? For logic operations, `and`, `or`, etc are used.

Comment: -1: What is the use case for this?  Why does this matter?

Comment: I don't really know what my expectations were, but i definitely did not expect this to happen.

Comment: @S.Lott I think it matters because the difference between (and / +) for boolean types isn't necessarily obvious, so it's a question worth asking.

Comment: This is **not concatenation**; `+` means addition, and interpreting concatenation as a special kind of addition is specific to strings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because In Python, `bool` is the subclass/subtype of `int`.

```
>>> issubclass(bool,int)
True
```

**Update**:

From [**boolobject.c**](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/boolobject.c)

```
/* Boolean type, a subtype of int */

/* We need to define bool_print to override int_print */
bool_print
    fputs(self->ob_ival == 0 ? "False" : "True", fp);

/* We define bool_repr to return "False" or "True" */
bool_repr
    ...

/* We define bool_new to always return either Py_True or Py_False */
    ...

// Arithmetic methods -- only so we can override &, |, ^
bool_as_number
    bool_and,       /* nb_and */
    bool_xor,       /* nb_xor */
    bool_or,        /* nb_or */

PyBool_Type
    "bool",
    sizeof(PyIntObject),
    (printfunc)bool_print,          /* tp_print */
    (reprfunc)bool_repr,            /* tp_repr */
    &bool_as_number,                /* tp_as_number */
    (reprfunc)bool_repr,            /* tp_str */
    &PyInt_Type,                    /* tp_base */
    bool_new,                       /* tp_new */
```

Comment: Wonderful. Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 8):

Replace "concatenate" with "add" and `True`/`False` with `1`/`0`, as you've said, and it makes perfect sense.

> To sum up True and False  in a sentence: they're alternative ways to spell the integer values 1 and 0, with the single difference that str() and repr()  return the strings 'True' and 'False' instead of '1'  and '0'.

See also: http://www.python.org/dev/doc/maint23/whatsnew/section-bool.html

Answer (score 2):

```
True is 1
False is 0
+ is ADD
```

Try this:

```
IDLE 2.6.4      
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
>>>
```